# Módulo não é carregado no php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, zend

Olá, estou tentando baixar um pacote do composer e ele aponta que a extensão soap não está habilitada.

```
- nfephp-org/sped-nfe v5.0.97 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
```

Porém verifiquei no meu php.ini a extensão soap e ela está descomentada.
[image: Meu php. ini]

Entretanto, quando listo os módulos do php com php -m ela não aparece.

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: 1. Verifique se os arquivos da extensão existem; 2. Verifique (com `php -i | grep ini`) se você está editando o *php.ini* correto; 3. Reinicie o PHP após alterações no *php.ini*.

Comment: O PHP encontraria essas configurações a partir de locais pré-definidos a saber:

1. Módulos SAPI
2. Variáveis de ambiente do PHPRC (caso esteja rodando a versão 5.2)
3. Chaves de registro pré-definidas no Windows
4. Arquivos que estejam no seu diretório atual
5. Diretórios no lado do servidor
6. Aqueles diretórios configurados com a opção --with-config-file-path ou dentro da pasta do Windows.

Dúvida? Esse assunto está esmiuçado aqui: [link](http://php.net/configuration.file)
Com o `php -i | grep ini` vc será capaz de identificar caminhos que DEVERIAM estar bem apontados.